# How to connect Laravel application to MySQL without password in Windows

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.8

I am using Laravel 5.8 and connecting with MySQL in Windows where I am not using any password in MySQL.

i run

`php artisan make:auth`

but there are didn't create any table in the database.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306 
DB_DATABASE=laraveltest
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

I expect to connect database and create tables in the database

Comment: can u run this command `php artisan migrate` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`php artisan make:auth` will only make a migration file for authentication related tables which will be saved on `database > migration` folder.

You'll need to run `php artisan migrate`.

`php artisan migrate` is the actual command that would create tables on your database.

Here is the link for the documentation: [php artisan migrate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#running-migrations)